# Changes Needed after changing package structure of android project?

Tags: android

I am doing one android project in android studio,previously it was working totally fine in Genymotion as well as in actual Mobile phone.

But later when it was needed , I changed my package structure,I made related changes in **AndroidManifest.xml** and **build.gradle**.Still after that,it was running perfectly on **Genymotion** but when I tried running it on mobile phone,it is showing error

> Waiting for device.
>
> Target device: samsung-gt_b5330-4d000ef10dee7f00
>
> Uploading file
>
> local path: F:\AppName\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk
>
> remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.aaa
>
> Installing com.aaa
>
> DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.aaa"
>
> pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.aaa
>
> Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]

for example let me tell you how old package was for some classes

> com.aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd

so my common package for all activity was

> com.aaa.bbb

mean all other packages was under this package

so my **R** package was **com.aaa.bbb.R**

but then added some data under **com.aaa** package

so my new common package became **com.aaa**

because of that new **R** position became **com.aaa.R**

because of that I changed

```
import com.aaa.R
```

in all classes

also i changed in **AndroidManifest.xml** to

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.aaa" >
```

(previously it was **package="com.aaa.bbb"**)

also changed in build.gradle to

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.aaa" //previously it was applicationId "com.aaa.bbb"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

so where else I should make changes ?

Answer (score 1):

The package name on the device must be unique, and there is a conflict when you try to install OVER the existing APK (that is what this means: "Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]")

You should completely delete the old APK from your device, and you will be able to install the new version.

Comment: I uninstalled my app,still it was showing error so I done "Factory Data Reset"(completely formatted my mobile) .But still it it is showing same error.so fault must not because of mobile.